# ORACLE APEX CREATE LOGON TRIGGER

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to update a status to my table with specific criteria (where clause) when any user logs on..

```
create or replace TRIGGER AUTO_COMPLETE
AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
    UPDATE SESSIONS
    SET SESSIONS.STATUS = 5
    WHERE SESSIONS.STATUS =2
    AND TO_CHAR(SESSIONS.SESSION_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24.MM') < TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24.MM');
END AUTO_COMPLETE;
```

Unfortunately this trigger is not fired and i have no errors!!

Comment: A logon trigger fires when a user logs in to the Oracle database, creating a new database session.  It sounds like you want something to happen when a user logs in to your APEX application.  If so, that logic should be part of your authentication process in APEX, not in a logon trigger in the database.

Comment: As an aside, it seems rather unlikely that your `session_date` predicate is right.  You're converting both `session_date` and `sysdate` to strings and doing a string comparison but your string formats mean that string and date comparison semantics will return different results.  The string '01-01-2021' sorts before the string '02-01-2000' alphabetically but the date it represents is obviously later.

Comment: Justin is correct in the trigger not firing because users aren't creating database sessions when connecting through APEX. I also made the same observation on the date predicate. Why not just compare session_date and sysdate directly if session_date is also a date data type?

Comment: Justin and pmdba thank you for your response.! You are right!! I will create something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex is stateless, see first paragraph [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEMIG/understanding-key-differences.htm#AEMIG145). That means that a new database session is created for every page render or post process. I think that would make that logon trigger fire constantly when the user navigates around the application.

You could create an application process with point "After Authentication" in your application. That will fire only once for the application after the user authenticates.

Keeping this functionality separate from your database makes sense. A logon trigger will fire when you connect through sqldeveloper or over rest as well - and it will affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is in your app settings, you can user bind variables to verify the username or another stuff.

```
Shared components / Security Attributes / Database Session
```

[image]

Or another option is to create a process after authentication

[image]

Comment: The "Initialization PL/SQL Code" is executed at the start of every database session, not when user logs on. APEX will initialize a new session on every page click (apex is stateless) so that block will be run for every page click. I don't think that is what the OP meant.